# Merge [rewrite] into [url-rewriting]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-block-request

Merge [rewrite](/questions/tagged/rewrite) into [url-rewriting](/questions/tagged/url-rewriting).

Currently, according to the tag wiki, [rewrite](/questions/tagged/rewrite) is about URL rewriting, so they should be merged.

Maybe blacklist [rewrite](/questions/tagged/rewrite) for ambiguity; otherwise synonymize.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly [rewrite](/questions/tagged/rewrite) is used for url-rewriting on Stackoverflow.

But there are many questions that have [rewrite](/questions/tagged/rewrite) for file-rewriting. Rewrite means replacing subterms of a formula/code/string with other terms. So it would be create problem if we directly merge tags.

Some of questions are:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608787/zend-rewrite-base
2. [Write in a file but delete on exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318686/write-in-a-file-but-delete-on-exit)
3. [Rewriting into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484258/rewriting-into-a-file)
4. [Python. How to edit data in text database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271084/python-how-to-edit-data-in-text-database)
5. [Rewrite a file that the program already used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583603/rewrite-a-file-that-the-program-already-used)
6. [suggestion required related to rewriting and string manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924043/suggestion-required-related-to-rewriting-and-string-manipulation)